# Performance issue with QML QChart

Tags: javascript, html, qt, qml, chart.js

I am using QML bindings for Charts.js, which is based on HTML5 javascript library using the canvas element.

I am trying to use a LinePlot and add data to it during run time. But it gets really slow just a few seconds after i start it.

I am not sure if my code is the reason for the slowdown or the library. Is there anything I can optimize to make my plot behave more smoothly?

I have made the RealtimePlot component below:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import jbQuick.Charts 1.0


Rectangle {
    property var label: []
    property var values: []
    property int length: 0

    Timer {
        id: dataTimer
        interval: 100
        repeat: true
        onTriggered: addData([5, 10])
    }

    Timer {
        id: plotUpdateTimer
        interval: 100
        repeat: true
        running: true
        onTriggered: {
            chart.repaint()
        }
    }

    Chart {
        id: chart
        height: parent.height
        width: parent.width
        chartAnimated: false
        //chartAnimationEasing: Easing.InOutElastic
        //chartAnimationDuration: 2
        chartType: Charts.ChartType.LINE
        Component.onCompleted: {

            //Start simulated data timer.
            dataTimer.start()

            //Set data visual properties and data/label variables.
            chartData = {
                labels: label,
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: "Dataset",
                        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                        pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                        data: values
                    },
                ]
            };
        }
    }

    function addData(data)
    {
        //Add new labels/values.
        for (var i = length; i < (length + data.length); i++)
        {
            label.push(i)
            values.push(data[i - length])
        }

        //Update total labels/values length.
        length += data.length
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a link to this library, please?

Comment: @folibis [here](https://github.com/jwintz/qchart.js/tree/master) it is. I've played around with the original and it is pretty cool. Didn't know about the even cooler QML binding. Good to know. :)

Comment: Thanks, @BaCaRoZzo. The library looks nice but as i see it based on `Canvas`. As for me that a bit slow, with big amount of data.

Comment: More or less...it really depends on the amount of data, the refresh rate and so on. I've 12 canvases updated in parallel and in realtime in my app. By tweaking the input and play around with the different options (and a wise approach with the background) I've obtained a stable framerate even on old devices (Galaxy S, iPod fifth edition and similar). Surely drawing directly with FBO (or something in the between) would result in better performances. It always reduces to a trade-off between performance and functionality. :)

Comment: Note that we have also created a little binding for Chart.js 2... maybe, it helps you: https://github.com/Elypson/ChartJs2QML